# How to use axios PUT method in React when there is authentication required?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Like the title says, I need to use PUT method with axios in react, but also I need to have authentication. I am using this api: https://gorest.co.in/ , and on the site as you can see for PUT mehtod, you are required to use access token which can be provided to you when you login onto the site. Now, I have done that, and I got my token, but somehow I still get 401 status code a.k.a I am unauthorized for PUT method, here is what I have done:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .put(
    "https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/6",
    {
      name: "Test",
      body: "This is an updated user",
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "my token, for privacy reasons I am deleting it, but it goes here",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    setData(response.data);
  });
```

});

This is my first time doing PUT method so I am really confused on what I am doing wrong here. If someone could help me, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Did you check it with postman ?

Comment: I think it's better to create an instance and once add the token for each methods, in this case, you don't need to set this for anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the word *Bearer* before your token?
Like:

```
Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>
```

Comment: I do not, do I need to have it?

Comment: Yes. It's OAuth protocol requiring it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```json
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${myToken}`,
  },
}
```

The website defines the header like this
`Authorization: Bearer ACCESS-TOKEN`